# Copy custom list value to var or dynamic and loop through?

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, objectdatasource

In my objectdatasource i am using _selected event to get some value from the list which object returns.

So i am using  `e.Returnvalue`.

```
protected void ObjTrailerList_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {

        dynamic details = e.ReturnValue;
       var d = e.ReturnValue;}
```

Now i want to copy entire custom list value to var or dynamic n iterate through.
How to do? I don't want to create object List of MovieTrailers and copy the value in it.

my custom list is

```
public class MovieTrailers
{
   public int? TrailerId
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   public string MovieName
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   public string TrailerUrl
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why -1 vote???? what wrong stuff did i ask???

Comment: You didn't give enough detail, or show us what you're trying to do. Fix that, and maybe the close votes will stop.

Comment: oh...what i tried gave me errors so i didn't post the code. i have option to create List<MovieTrailers> which i don't want to. i will post i am trying. i posted how i am copying to var or dymaic..now i have no idea how to iterate through them.

Comment: i do accept answers but i didn't get exact answer so i didn't accept the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void TestDynamic(dynamic list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item is string)
        {
            string foo = item;//use it as string
            Console.WriteLine("The string is: {0}", foo);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}

static void Mian()
{
    //pass a list of strings
    TestDynamic(new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" });

    //pass a list of anonymous class
    TestDynamic(new List<dynamic> { new { Age = 25, BirthDay = new DateTime(1986, 1, 3) }, new { Age = 0, BirthDay = DateTime.Now } });

    //TestDynamic(25);//this will cause exception at run time at the foreach line
}


//output:
The string is: Foo
The string is: Bar
The string is: Baz
{ Age = 25, BirthDay = 3/1/1986 00:00:00 }
{ Age = 0, BirthDay = 23/6/2011 01:23:18 }
```

Comment: Thanks Jalal... it works.. i had to modify as per my need.. Thanks a lot.s